# How to limit choices for a Many to Many relation?

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield, limit-choices-to

I'm using Python + Django and have this in my model right now:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    player = models.ManyToManyField(Player, related_name="player", through="Team_Player")
    squad = models.ManyToManyField(Player, related_name="squad", blank=True)

class Player(Person):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Team_Player(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
```

Is there a way to limit Team.squad to only have players inside Team.player relationship? I was trying to use limit_choices_to with no luck so far. Any clues?

Comment: I think you might have some redundancy with your `Team_Player` model.  could you describe what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: The model structure seem quite messy. Besides that - you can override the save() method or to use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save PRE-SAVE signal to check if a squad has players from the team only, and to raise an ValueError if that's not matched.

Comment: I believe your looking for this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621494/django-limiting-the-number-of-relationships-in-a-onetomany-relationship

Comment: you are* (couldn't edit my previously comment)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in the Django ORM. You will need to refactor your design so that a team is composed of squads, and a squad is composed of players; add a property or method to the team model to get all players in the current team.