# How do I model a registration system with the following relationship constraints in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, relationship

I am trying to create a hackathon management system web application using Django. Each hackathon can have as many participating universities as possible (No constraints here).Now, each participating university can have at most 3 teams and each team can have at most 4 persons (1-4). I'm new to Django so help would be much appreciated.

```
from django.db import models


class Hackathon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,default='')
    eventId = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
    startDate = models.DateField(null=True)
    endDate = models.DateField(null=True)
    location = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=800, blank=True, default='')
    #participants = models.ManyToManyField(...)??

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class University(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    member_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(4)])
    uni = models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(Team,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: The best start in the case is to understand what database you are using. Models are in the simplest form tables in a database. Understand what DB you are using will help you understand how to build your models. Think about how a DB works, how to limit, how to add constraints and how to build your data to the needs of the project. This answer may help with limiting the number of objects acceptable to the goal of your project.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621494/django-limiting-the-number-of-relationships-in-a-onetomany-relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relational schema seems right for the use-case you describe.

The constraints you describe (*at most 3 teams and each team can have at most 4 persons*) are not really *DB constraints* but rather *application constraints*. You will probably have to define a **validation logic** in overriding your Models `save()` method.

```
class Team(models.Model):

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.uni.teams.count() >= 3:
      raise ValidationError("This university already has its 3 teams")
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)



class Person(models.Model):

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.team.persons.count() >= 4:
      raise ValidationError("This team already has its 4 people")
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Also, I would recommend you to use [Django 'User' model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/), which comes with several utils : password management, username unicity, ...etc.